# How can I rotate my hitbox with my rotating and moving car in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to collide my car sprite with another rect, right now I am using rect collisions and my car collision [video](https://gyazo.com/737f66a31670e8efffd0b8930c66b9c9), but each time I rotate the hitbox it moves somewhere else.

Is there a way I could collide my car sprite with that hitbox instead of using a car hitbox?

My car class:

```py
            class Car:
              def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
              self.x = x - width / 2
            self.y = y - height / 2
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, height, width)
            self.surface = pygame.Surface((height, width), pygame.SRCALPHA)
            self.surface.blit(img, (0, 0))
            self.angle = 250
            self.speed = 0# 2

            self.hitbox = (self.x + 90, self.y + 620, 370, 63)# CARS HITBOX
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)

            def draw(self): #3
            self.rect.topleft = (int(self.x), int(self.y))
            rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, self.angle)
            surface_rect = self.surface.get_rect(topleft = self.rect.topleft)
            new_rect = rotated.get_rect(center = surface_rect.center)
            window.blit(rotated, new_rect.topleft)
            self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 70, 40)# CARS HITBOX BLITTING AT car x, y
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)# draw the car hitbox

            white = (255, 255, 255)
            car1 = Car(100, 630, 73, 73, white)# 4
```

My full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Yr8wD9Wm)

Comment: you could try [Masks](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) which is used for pixel perfect collision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I rotate my hitbox with my rotating and moving car in pygame?

You don't. You have to use [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) and [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap).
A mask can be created from a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) by [`pygame.mask.from_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface) and contains the information about the  opaque pixels. `overlap()` finds the 1 opaque pixel in 2 masks, which are intersecting.

For instance:

```py
class Car:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        # [...]

        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(rotated)
        self.mask_rect = new_rect
```

```py
obstacle_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(obstacle_surface)

offset_x = obstacle_rect.x - car1.mask_rect.x
offset_y = obstacle_rect.y - car1.mask_rect.y

if car1.mask.overlap(obstacle_mask, (offset_x, offset_y)):
    print("hit")
```

Note, the offset argument of `overlap()`, is the offset from this mask to the other mask (to the 1st argument). It is the vector from the mask to the other mask in the argument. If the location of *self* is (*x1*, *y1*) and the location of *other* is (*x2*, *y2*) then the offset is (*x2 - x1*, *y2 - y1*).

---

If the obstacle is just a rectangle and you don't have a Surface (<s>`obstacle_surface`</s>), then you can generate a completely opaque Mask form the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) (`obstacle_rect`) object:

```py
obstacle_mask = pygame.mask.Mask(obstacle_rect.width, True)
```

Comment: may I ask what the obstacle_surface is?

Comment: !? Anything you want. Any other `pygame.Surface` object.

Comment: umm I tried to put my car1.rect for obstacle_surface but I am not sure why I am getting an error what object am I suppose to but also  I am not sure what to do for the obstacle_rect.x ?? do I put car1.x? and for the other one car1.y?

Comment: @HabibIsmail No. You are testing car against something else. So obstacle can't be car.

Comment: Oh so I could test it with my other object rect?

Comment: @HabibIsmail What you need is another Surface (and of course a rectangle)

Comment: sorry if I am asking to much questions but in my main loop what I have done is 
        `obstacle_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(hole1)

        offset_x = hole1.x - car1.mask_rect.x
        offset_y = hole1.y - car1.mask_rect.y

        if car1.mask.overlap(obstacle_mask, (offset_x, offset_y)):
            print("hit")`
I am getting this error `TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not hole`

Comment: @HabibIsmail `hole1` has to be a Surface not a rectangle. A mask can only be generated from a surface. If you don't have a surface, then you can generate a Surface from a rectangle: `obstacle_mask = pygame.mask.Mask(hole1.width, True)`. I've extended the answer.